# Long table, grouped by factors and refernce to inital position

Tags: r, grouping

Consider the following MWE. I want to calculate the distance travelled in relation to the initial time step for each person. Take the following:

```
time <- rep(1:3,2)
lin.posi <- c(200,175,150,200,190,180)
person <- c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3))

df1 <- data.frame(time, lin.posi, person)
```

I want how far person A is from time=1 for each time step (t=1,2,3) and then calculate the same for person B.

The output should be:

```
# df1$rel.dis <- c(0,25,50,0,10,20)
```

I am have tried to use `dplyr` but maybe the `data.table` experts wizards can provide an insight

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(person) %>% 
  lin.posi[1] - lin.posi
```

Comment: Did you try `df1 %>%
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(rel.dis = lin.posi[1] - lin.posi)` ? Or are you looking for a data.table solution?

Comment: in base R, you can use ave: `ave(df$lin.posi, df$person, FUN=function(i) i - i[1])` as long as the data is sorted as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution would be:

```
setDT(df1)[,rel.dis := (lin.posi[time==1] - lin.posi) , by = person]
df1
#   time lin.posi person rel.dis
#1:    1      200      A       0
#2:    2      175      A      25
#3:    3      150      A      50
#4:    1      200      B       0
#5:    2      190      B      10
#6:    3      180      B      20
```